# regex evaluation so as to return all cells that are a match

Tags: java, aspose-cells

```
               FindOptions opt = new FindOptions();

            opt.setRegexKey(true); 
            opt.setLookAtType(LookAtType.ENTIRE_CONTENT);
            Cells cells = workbook.getWorksheets().get(1).getCells();
            String regex = "<.*>";

            System.out.println(cells.find(regex, null, opt));
```

This only prints the first cell that matches the regex . How can I get a collection of all the cells that match the regex?

Comment: What happens if you pass the result of the first find as second parameter in the next call to find, and so on, until the result is null?

Answer (score 0):

You got to use some loop to find each cell that matches in the worksheet, see the sample code segment for your reference:
e.g
Sample code:

```
..........
Cells cells = workbook.getWorksheets().get(1).getCells();
Cell cell;
Cell prevcell = null;
String regex = "<.*>";
FindOptions opt = new FindOptions();

            opt.setRegexKey(true); 
            opt.setLookAtType(LookAtType.ENTIRE_CONTENT);


do {

                    cell = cells.find(regex, prevcell, opt);
 System.out.println("Name:" + cell.getName() + " Value:" + cell.getStringValue());  

                    if (cell == null)
                        break;

                    prevcell = cell;

                } while (cell != null);

................
```

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.